# How to Set Character Set in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i've some issue with setting character set in pdo. Below is my connection code :-

```
private function Connect()
{
    $this->settings = parse_ini_file("settings.ini.php");
    //$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$this->settings["dbname"].';host='.$this->settings["host"].'';
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $this->settings["dbname"] . ';host=' . $this->settings["host"] .';charset=utf8'. ';connect_timeout=15';
    try 
    {       
        # Read settings from INI file, set UTF8
        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->settings["user"], $this->settings["password"], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

        # We can now log any exceptions on Fatal error. 
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        # Disable emulation of prepared statements, use REAL prepared statements instead.
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        # Connection succeeded, set the boolean to true.
        $this->bConnected = true;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        # Write into log
        echo $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage());
        die();
    }
}
```

I am inserting french character as `céréales` but it is storing as      `cÃ©rÃ©ales` in DB. Anyone know how to set character set to utf8 in pdo?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: i'd tried that but it didn't work either

Comment: You tried what exactly?What is the charset and collation of your database and table?

Comment: utf8mb4_unicode_ci is the collation for the tables and utf8mb4 is the charset. My site was in mysql previously there i was able to set charset after the connection. I'd converted the whole site in pdo and its not working now.

Comment: What does this show you for character_set_server `show variables like 'char%';`

Answer (score 1):

You are already setting the utf8 charset in the connection string. You don't have to send another query like "SET NAMES 'uft8'".

You just have to make sure that:

- Mysql table and field are utf8 (like uft8_general_ci)
- Input data is utf-8

The `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")` is also useless. This is the faster way to set all your parameters:

```
$this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->settings["host"].';dbname='.$this->settings["dbname"].';
      charset=utf8;connect_timeout=15', $this->settings["user"], $this->settings["password"], 
      array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```